# Typesafe map assignment and retrieval

Tags: kotlin, typing

I am trying to proxy calls for Observables and LiveData (similar to the Mediator pattern), but I could not find a typesafe solution. This is the problem:

```
class Proxy {
    private val backupMap = HashMap<LiveData<Any>, Observer<Any>>()

     fun <T> add(liveData : LiveData<T>, observer : Observer<T>) {
         // !This is the issue LiveData<Any> is expected
         backupMap.put(liveData, observer)
     }

    fun attach() {
        backupMap.forEach { (key, value) ->
            key.observeForever(value)
        }
    }
}

fun addSome() {
    Proxy().apply {
        add(MutableLiveData<String>(), Observer {  })
    }
}
```

I could cast `backupMap.put` to `backupMap.put(liveData as LiveData<Any>, observer as Observer<Any>)` but this causes an `Unchecked Cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found is to use an intermediate object to hold the typesafe binding:

```
private  val backupMap: MutableMap<LiveData<*>, Attacher<*>> 

private class Attacher<A>(private val lifeData: LiveData<A>, private val observer : Observer<A>) {
        fun attach() {
            lifeData.observeForever(observer)
        }

        fun detach() {
            lifeData.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
```